# Packaging output from groovy into a jar

Tags: java, groovy, jar, executable-jar

I tried taking an extremely simple groovy script

```
class HelloGroovy {
    public static void main(args) {
        println("hello groovy")
    }
}
```

and compiling it into a a `.class` file via `groovy`

```
mkdir out && groovyc helloGroovy.groovy
```

the only contents of the out directory is a single class file

```
cd out && ls
> HelloGroovy.class
```

I tried packaging this class into a jar with HelloGroovy as an entry point.

```
jar cfe foo.jar HelloGroovy HelloGroovy.class
```

but when I tried to run the resulting jar it could not load the main class using `java -jar foo.jar`

```
java -jar foo.jar
> Error: could not find or load main class HelloGroovy
```

I checked the jar file and the manifest lists `HelloGroovy` as `Main-Class` and `javap HelloGroovy.class` shows that there is a main method with the appropriate argument structure.

```
public class HelloGroovy implements groovy.lang.GroovyObject {
  public static transient boolean __$stMC;
  public HelloGroovy();
  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
  protected groovy.lang.MetaClass $getStaticMetaClass();
  public groovy.lang.MetaClass getMetaClass();
  public void setMetaClass(groovy.lang.MetaClass);
  public java.lang.Object invokeMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);
  public java.lang.Object getProperty(java.lang.String);
  public void setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);
}
```

Why can't java find the HelloGroovy class and execute the main method?

It makes sense to me that the program would fail to print because the groovy standard library is not on the classpath as far a I know. However, I would still expect it to be able to find the original class and am confused.

Comment: Does it work when you put groovy-all.jar on the classpath?

Comment: I only have one `groovy-all.jar` file associated and it is associated with the netbeans application. I don't know how `groovy` and `groovyc` in the brew package work, but I don't seem to have a `groovy-all.jar` file.

Comment: Have you installed groovy?

Comment: Yes groovy, groovyc via homebrew. Groovyc was how I compiled the classfiles to begin with.

Comment: Ahhhh... I always use gvmtool... Is there an `embeddable` folder wherever homebrew installed it? The 'all' jar will be in there

Comment: I've checked the startgroovy shell script and it does add groovy-2.4.4 to the classpath. I'm just confused because it seems like it should still be able to find the HelloGroovy class even without the standard groovy library included.

Comment: Even if that were the case, it wouldn't work as it wouldn't find groovy. Have you tried putting the groovy jar on the classpath?